# DevOps hosted pipeline fail to build .NET Core 2.2

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-devops-hosted-agent

With the [release of .NET Core 2.2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/12/04/announcing-net-core-2-2/) I expected to be able to build such projects in our Microsoft-hosted DevOps (Azure) pipeline. But the restore step fails, saying 2.2 is not supported:

```
2018-12-11T14:57:49.0856135Z        "D:\a\1\s\My.Project\My.Project.csproj" (Restore target) (1) ->
2018-12-11T14:57:49.0857867Z        "D:\a\1\s\MyProject.EntityFramework\MyProject.EntityFramework.csproj" (_GenerateRestoreGraphProjectEntry target) (2:3) ->
2018-12-11T14:57:49.0858029Z        (_CheckForUnsupportedNETCoreVersion target) -> 
2018-12-11T14:57:49.0858191Z          C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.402\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(137,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.2.  Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.2. [D:\a\1\s\MyProject.EntityFramework\MyProject.EntityFramework.csproj]
2018-12-11T14:57:49.0858287Z 
2018-12-11T14:57:49.0858338Z 
2018-12-11T14:57:49.0858398Z        "D:\a\1\s\My.Project\My.Project.csproj" (Restore target) (1) ->
2018-12-11T14:57:49.0858504Z        "D:\a\1\s\My.Project\My.Project.csproj" (_GenerateRestoreGraphProjectEntry target) (1:5) ->
2018-12-11T14:57:49.0858645Z          C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.402\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(137,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.2.  Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.2. [D:\a\1\s\My.Project\My.Project.csproj]
```

The project builds fine locally, so I think it is most likely that I'm missing something - especially as I come up with nothing on my internet search for similar errors.

Could it really be it is not supported yet?

Comment: `2.1.402` there's yer problem

Comment: Right, but this is Microsoft's hosted build agent in Azure. I don't have control over it but I expect MS to support latest and greatest.

Comment: What image are you using in your pipeline?

Comment: Microsof't canned "Hosted VS2017".

Comment: 2.2 is not a LTS release, so it is latest but not the "greatest" https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support-policy

Comment: @lexli how do you mean? this page:  https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support-policy/dotnet-core on the support table, 2.2.0 is clearly listed perhaps not at the time?

Comment: @akousmata I meant what I typed. Not an LTS release has a series of consequences, especially on tooling side (for instance, a build machine might only contains LTS tooling, 2.1.402, but no other).

Comment: You can use this [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/master/images/win/Vs2017-Server2016-Readme.md) to see what is pre-installed on the build machines.

Answer (score 15):

OK, so there is a task ".NET Core Installer" that can be added before the Restore task, and by requesting 2.2.100 to be installed first of all the build passes.

Comment: The task is now called ".NET Core SDK Installer" . For anyone looking for a valid version for 2.1, I found that 2.1.500 works.  Surprised that neither 2.1.0 nor 2.2.0 exists.

Comment: What a PITA... firstly the hosted agent should have 2.2 installed already, and secondly Microsoft really need to surface things like this in the UI somehow - I shouldn't have to resort to Google and SO :/

Answer (score 5):

This does trick to my project:

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core SDK Tool Installer'
  inputs:
    version: 2.2.100
- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with my pipeline. Here is the solution:

1. Add to your job (press plus button) in the pipeline task **.NET Core SDK Installer**. You can search for it in a search box
   [image: Task adding]
2. Make sure to put that task on the top of your job. You can use drag&drop.

[image: Put .Net SDK on the top]

3. Set up version of .Net Core SDK Installer at least the same your version.

[image: Set up .Net Core SDK]

You can see all available version by pressing on the "[here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/releases.json)" word the in the popup

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @bit0001 is correct. Microsoft has a list of supported versions that can be installed using this task. You can find those versions [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/releases-index.json).

As you can see, 2.1.500 is supported when installing the `sdk`, 2.1.0 is not, you'll need to use 2.1.300. When installing only the runtime, you can use 2.1.0. Currently, the latest 2.2 version supported is 2.2.100.

Comment: Link is no longer valid

Comment: Fixed the link as requested by @lance